# Exif data tool and profile color

Tags: photoshop, metadata

I would like to know in a exif data what is the difference between profile CMM type lino and profile CMM type n/a
What does it means Profile CMM type?

Answer (score 1):

CMM stands for "color management module", and the ProfileCMMType tag apparently indicates the kind of color management profile used. I've seen values like `lino`, `adbe`, and `appl`. `n/a` could mean that the tag wasn't included in the EXIF data. I looked briefly but wasn't able to find a list of valid or common values.